# What exactly does the Photos.app repair library function do?

Tags: photos.app, repair

My Photos library seems to be in pretty decent shape, but I noticed that since the last major macOS upgrade I did (to Monterey), it is having trouble with keeping "People" from becoming duplicates.

To explain more, I have (say) Jane in numerous records in the photo library. However, when I go to a photo where she is tagged as 'unknown' and I try to start typing in her name, it doesn't pop up as a known name and I end up creating a new "Person" for her. This ends up with me having to go back to the "everyone" page and then merging the old and new Jane records together as one person.

This doesn't happen for everyone, but it happens enough to be really annoying. It seems like it happens more with people I haven't tagged in a while, but they DO exist in my People page.

So that backstory aside, I've been trying to find ways to fix the library so that it will stop doing this annoying behavior. Naturally, you would think that "repair library" would attempt to resolve something like this. However, I'm just concerned that it will break something.

So thus the question: what *exactly* does the Photos.app repair library do? It would be nice to know what it is attempting before I just throw it at my library and possibly lose something (metadata or photos) in the process.

*(For clarity, the photo library is locally hosted and NOT synced with iCloud. However, I do have iCloud shared albums enabled so that I can create/view shared albums)*

Comment: Have you got iCloud photos syncing on?

Comment: I have shared albums from iCloud, but I do not sync my album with iCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of Apple documenting the code / steps for repair - but it's widely known that there are databases that track everything and that databased need to be checked and cross referenced, permissions validated, files checked on disk and maintenance routines to reclaim space from deleted entries / rebuild indexes / other database maintenance steps.

It's also not clear if the repair changes over time - but there is a pragmatic thing you can do and that's to back up your Mac / the database before you attempt a repair in case it causes issues.

I had similar issues and worked with Apple support to validate my plan and it was well worth my time. As much as I think I can reason about Apple software - they had some tips and steps I would never have considered. They also can get the logs and escalate to engineering where they can look at iCloud and potentially have you set a specific flag to rebuild the one item that ails you.

What I do know is after that support case, my People albums have behaved so much better between my various devices and I did walk away from one of my three Macs that synced that library - it just wasn't working like the rest so I made sure the main Mac that keeps all originals was good and then wiped the problem second backup Mac.

I also used the tool https://fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/ since I had my issues from before Apple introduced the duplicate culling interface to Photos. I would 100% recommend that software if Apple can't help you sort things before you disable iCloud and start anew with one library you like and sync all the rest via iCloud. Luckily - I didn't have to do that final step I describe, but it was my next move if my People album couldn't be revived or coaxed back to health.

Comment: I've tried the PowerPhotos app on this as well, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue I'm experiencing with it not attempting to suggest/complete names which it already knows about. Will see if it gets resolved when I upgrade this machine to Ventura and its newer version of Photos.app.

Comment: Sounds good @bjb - I've used Power Photos to move the photos into a new library more than "fix" a broken one TBH... Just makes it easier to walk away from broken if / when that happens